# Why does the set function in Python produce different outputs for the same inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

This is my code

```py
string='AABCAAADA'
k=3
for i in range(0,len(string),k):
    print(set(string[i:i+k]))
```

each time I run it produces a different output. how can i fix this?

outputs:

```
{'B', 'A'}
{'A', 'C'}
{'D', 'A'}
```

```
{'B', 'A'}
{'C', 'A'}
{'D', 'A'}
```

```
{'A', 'B'}
{'A', 'C'}
{'A', 'D'}
```

Comment: That is outputting *the same sets*. Set objects are inherently unordered.

Answer (score 1):

Because `set()` returns set, which by design is unordered collection.